# Java Streams Split a list into sub-lists, process those lists individually and merge them back

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a use case, in which a list containing 'Location' objects needs to be processed based on locationName.
I tried this with Java 8 streams,

```
private List<Payment> filterLocationsByName(List<Location> locationList) {
    return locationList.stream().filter(l -> l.getLocationName()
           .equalsIgnoreCase("some_location_name"))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

List<Location> originalLocationList = .....
List<Location> someLocations = filterLocationsByName(originalLocationList);

//logic to process someLocations list

// do the same for another locationName

//at the end need to return the originalList with the changes made
```

My problem is someLocations list is not backed by the original list. Changes I do for someLocations elements are not populated in the original list. 
How can I merge this someLocations list back to the original list so that processed changes are in effect on the original list?

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised if you could.

Comment: `someLocations` is not backed by the original list but it contains references to the original objects, which are still also referenced from  `originalLocationList`.  If all you want to do is mutate the existing `Location` objects you can do that without needing to merge anything back. What's the question?

Comment: @Krishan Your question is unclear. `filterLocationsByName` returns a `List<Payment>` which you can't assign to a `List<Location>`. Moreover, `filterLocationsByName` is not tranforming the `List<Location>` to a `List<Payment>`. Not sure if this code will even compile.

Comment: There is already an error in the prerequisite. See [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--): “*There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned*”. Assuming that you can modify the returned list, is already an error. It happens to be possible in the current version of this specific implementation, but isn’t guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are mostly for immutable processing, so you normally don't change  the original stream source (collection). You could try with `forEach` but you would need to do removal yourself.

Another option is to use [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) from Collection interface (you just need to negate the condition):

```
locationList.removeIf(
    l -> !l.getLocationName().equalsIgnoreCase("some_location_name")
);
```

This will change the list in place.